# Getting rid of scrollbars in wxPython Panel subclass?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to subclass Panel, and with the code below, I'm hitting this problem:

[image: panel-test.png]

On the right, a normal wx.Panel is instantiated, and as is visible, it has no scrollbars. On the left, the subclass TImagePanel is instantiated (in the same way as the wx.Panel) - and as is visible, there are two thin green lines, which is how MATE desktop on Ubuntu 14.04 shows scrollbars (if you hover over them, you get a scrollbar element, which is shown on the screenshot; this is on Ubuntu 14.04, MATE desktop, python 2.7, python-wxgtk2.8 2.8.12.1).

What can I do in `TImagePanel` to get rid of these scrollbars?

**`TImagePanel.py`**

```python
import wx

# via https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/
class TImagePanel(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent, style):
    """Constructor"""
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, style=style)
    self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM) #(wx.BG_STYLE_ERASE)
    self.frame = parent
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

  def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
    """
    Add a picture to the background
    """
    # yanked from ColourDB.py
    dc = evt.GetDC()

    if not dc:
      dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
      rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
      dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
    dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.GetBackgroundColour())) # SO: 11766759
    dc.Clear()
```

**`paneltest.py`**

```python
import wxversion
wxversion.select("2.8")
import wx, wx.html
import sys

from TImagePanel import TImagePanel

class Frame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

    self.label = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "TImagePanel below left: ")
    bt_main = wx.Button(self, label="Click ME")
    bt_main.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.BtnClickHandler)

    sizer_vmain_app = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_vmain_app.Add(self.label, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=0)
    sizer_vmain_app.Add(bt_main, proportion=0, flag=0, border=0)

    self.mypanel = TImagePanel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    normpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    self.mypanel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(200, 200, 200))
    normpanel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(200, 200, 200))

    sizer_hpanel = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_hpanel.Add(self.mypanel, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=10)
    sizer_hpanel.Add(normpanel, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=10)
    sizer_vmain_app.Add(sizer_hpanel, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=0)

    self.SetSizer(sizer_vmain_app)
    self.Layout()

  def BtnClickHandler(self, event):
    print("Am clicked")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
  wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
  app_frame = Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
  app.SetTopWindow(app_frame)
  app_frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: what is the bitmap size you are trying to display on the left panel?

Comment: Hi @Igor - there is no bitmap (nor its size) in this example; which is what I find confusing.

Comment: and if you maximize the frame, scrollbar disappear?

Comment: @Igor - if I maximize the window fullscreep, scrollbars don't dissapear - and regardless if I make the window larger or smaller, they in fact remain the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Right, I think I got it. Since, when I resize the window, the sizes of scrollbars don't change, this indicates the problem has nothing to do with size of inner content (there is no inner content here, to begin with).

After some attempts, I noticed this line of code:

```
self.mypanel = TImagePanel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
```

Apparently, this was copied from a normal wx.Panel instantiation, which has a signature `__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style, name)`, where indeed, the argument after `parent` is `id`.

However, in my `TImagePanel` subclass, the constructor has a signature: `__init__(self, parent, style)`. So basically, this `wx.ID_ANY` which should have referred to an ID, propagated as a *style* when the parent class is inititialized in the constructor! So, it enabled all kindsa things, and very possibly `wx.ALWAYS_SHOW_SB` which forces display of scrollbars.

All I needed to do, then, was to put in instead:

```
self.mypanel = TImagePanel(self, 0)
```

... since styles are apparently bitmasked, the "don't change style" flag should be 0 (I couldn't otherwise find a wx.NO_STYLE flag); or to be more explicit with a predefined wx style:

```
self.mypanel = TImagePanel(self, wx.NO_BORDER)
```

In either of these cases, the scrollbars disappear and the subclassed item looks identical to the wx.Panel instance, which is what I wanted to achieve in this case.